# How should I set up a Development to Production Plone workflow?

Tags: plone, web-deployment

I worked with Plone 2 several years ago, but its workflow and security systems (not to mention the new theming engine) seem the best fit for a current project. Plone 4 looks much better from a usability standpoint, but in its drive not to force a particular setup on users, it has become a bit of a maze as to how best to host it on our public-facing Ubuntu servers. I’ve got Plone installed using the Unified Installer (in `/home/plone/Plone/zinstance`), and have been running it in the foreground for development, but I’m now going to need to set things up for the move to making this website live.

I want to achieve a development instance on the project server that we can use for our own customisations (with additional local instances on our desktops for testing before checking into the development instance), then a site that our client can test things on before they go live, and finally the live website.

In particular:

1. I’m assuming that the live site will be based on ZEO, while testing and development will be standalone; does that make sense?
2. At present, everything lives in `/home/plone/Plone`, while all our other (generally PHP CMS) sites are hosted from `/srv/<domain>/www`; everything for the domain is then backed up in one go. What’s the best way to layout the different Plone instances to fit into this?
3. What’s the best way to move our changes to buildouts and products through the cycle from development to testing and then to a live site? We currently have a basic deployment process using Mercurial for other systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current best practice is to use [buildout](http://www.buildout.org) to define a fully reproducible deployment.

Generally, you use a `production.cfg` and a `development.cfg` configuration that share configuration via inclusion, to tweak the deployment to the specific needs of either environment; you can expand on this model as needed. A big project might have a `staging.cfg` to deploy new features to a test environment first, for example.

Whether or not you use ZEO in development depends entirely on your use cases. Most development setups certainly do not need it, but in a large deployment that includes async workers you may find you need a ZEO server when developing anyway. Again, buildout will make switching your development environment around for changing needs easier, especially when combined with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage the various daemons used in the setup.

For the biggest deployment I manage, we use a combination of subversion and git, but only for historic reasons. This is all being moved to one git repository. In the end, the repository will hold the complete buildout with it's various configurations, `development.cfg`, `staging.cfg` and per-production-machine configuration files (one for each server in the production cluster). For a 3-machine ZEO setup, that'd be one `zeo.cfg` and `instances-1.cfg` and `instances-2.cfg`, for example. The core development eggs are stored in the same repository in `src/`.

Development takes place *exclusively* in per-feature and per-issue branches. Once complete, a branch is merged into the staging branch, and the staging server is updated and restarted. Once the customer has signed off on each merged branch, and a roll-out has been planned, we merge the approved branches to the main branch and tag a release. The production cluster machines are then switched to that new tag and restarted.

We also use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for continuous integration testing; both the main and the staging branches are put through their tests at least once a day, letting us catch problems early.

All daemons are managed by a dedicated supervisord, which is started via a crontab entry (`@reboot`), not the native OS `init.d` structure. This way we can manage the running daemons entirely with buildout. The buildouts even generate logrotate configurations and munin monitoring plugins; these are symlinked into the OS locations as needed.

Because a buildout is entirely self-contained, it doesn't matter *where* you set up the production buildout on a machine. Do pick something consistent, document it and stick to that. Make sure you have sufficient disk space for your daemon needs and otherwise not worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

1. ZEO or not - for production or development - depends on personal needs and preferences. Many devs use ZEO for production and development and many do not. ZEO is needed for scaling (multiple app servers)
2. Nobody cares...install Plone where you want it or need it...re-running buildout after moving an installation fixes relocation issues. It is your system, not ours...*you* decide.
3. Usually buildout configurations live in a repository and can be pulled on the production server from the repository....otherwise you need to copy over the related buildout files yourself some. Typical installation works like this:

   - run virtualenv
   - checkout the buildout configuration from git/subversion
   - run bootstrap
   - run buildout